# Get single row with maximum date in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I can't believe I have to ask this, but all the answers I search for are based on grouping against other values and aggregates. I have a single column Dataframe, and it's just dates, of the Spark date type. I want the most recent date and to bring it back to the driver.

```
------------
|  MyDate  |
------------
|2020-10-01|
|2020-10-02|
|2020-10-02|
------------
```

I've tried:
`df.groupBy("MyDate").agg(max("MyDate") as "max_date")`

But that just duplicates the data into a second column.

I know it's stupid simple, but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use `select` with `max` function like in usual **SQL**:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

Seq(
  "2020-10-01",
  "2020-10-06",
  "2020-10-03"
).toDF("date")
  .select(max(col("date")).name("max_date"))
  .show()

/*
+----------+
|  max_date|
+----------+
|2020-10-06|
+----------+
*/
```